# Why image files don't appear in loginscreen but appear in the Unlockscreen?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, css

I have a customized "mytheme.css" that used to be able to show the loginscreen and unlockscreen wallpapers or any other icons using the url command. Their paths used were specified relative to the "mytheme" directory, i.e. `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme`. For example,

```
/*login & unlock screens wallpaper*/
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url("assets/lockDialogGroup.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

/* switch colors */
.toggle-switch-us:checked {
  background-image: url("assets/toggle-on.svg");
}
```

However, recently somehow that **syntax for the url command does not work for the loginscreen but works for the unlockscreen in Ubuntu 18.04**. Meaning, I would be able to see my wallpaper in the unlockscreen but not in the loginscreen.

To fix this issue, I currently have to use the `file` command. However, doing so requires the full path of the wallpaper to be stated which is quite long. For example, the above lines with url command have to be revised to:

```
   background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets/lockDialogGroup.jpg);
```

and

```
background-image: url(file:///usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets/toggle-on.svg);
```

**What I don't understand is** that according to css, given that my theme's css file full path is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/mytheme.css`, the reference directory should be `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/`, and if the full path of the  wallpaper is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets/lockDialogGroup.jpg`, I should simply only need to declare a relative path like so to show the wallpaper:

```
  background: #2c001e url("assets/lockDialogGroup.jpg");
```

It is strange that this command works for the unlockscreen but does not work for the loginscreen. Bear in mind I had earlier set `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json` to show:

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "mytheme/mytheme.css",
    "enabledExtensions": [
        "ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com",
        "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com"
    ]
}
```

**So what gives?**

Answer (score 0):

***Workaround*** by trail n error

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

In default Ubuntu 18.04 Installation, If you observe the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` which is configured for GDM and lockscreen...

some part of the file `ubuntu.css` is

```
/* switch colors */
.toggle-switch-us:checked {
  background-image: url("ubuntu-toggle-on-us.svg");
}
.toggle-switch-intl:checked {
  background-image: url("ubuntu-toggle-on-intl.svg");
}
```

the url part indicates.. the .svg file paths are relative to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`

so, when you have `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/mytheme.css` and the image path is `url("assets/1.jpg")` simple copy the folder assets into `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`

This means, lockscreen will consider `url("assets/1.jpg")` as `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets/1.jpg`

and the GDM will consider `url("assets/1.jpg")` as `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/assets/1.jpg`

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
[sudo] password for pratap: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/MyTheme/MyTheme.css   100       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/MyTheme/MyTheme.css   100       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css            10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

GDM Screen
[image]

Lock Screen
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Alternatively instead of copy pasting the `assets` folder you can make a symbolic link of `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets` like below command.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme/assets /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, the best way would be first creating a symbolic link to `mytheme` directory like below command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/mytheme /usr/share/gnome-shell/
```

and then installing the update-alternatives like below command

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css gdm3.css /usr/share/gnome-shell/mytheme/mytheme.css 100
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css 
[sudo] password for pratap: 
There are 3 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/MyTheme/MyTheme.css         100       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/MyTheme/MyTheme.css         100       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/MyTheme/MyTheme.css   100       manual mode
  3            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css            10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pratap. Noted that by default that GDM will treat the "url" in `url("assets/1.jpg")` to mean `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`. Why is it then that in your Best Alternative that the "url" term refers to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/MyTheme/`? From my earlier try-and-error attempts, I found that the GDM always default to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` and I think it does not change.